# gson - Custom deserializer for polymorphic variables

Tags: java, gson

I'm using gson to convert java objects to and from json objects. I ran into a problem with polymorphism.

I have these requests which looks something like this:

```
{
  "method": "getUser",
  "methodParameters": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f",
    "data": {
      "u": "v",
      "x": "y"
    }
  },
  "version": "1.3"
}
```

Each request method has a different kind of data object. Naturally each data object extends a base class called RequestData.

I tried to create a custom deserializer but since it's the request object and not the data object that holds the method, I could not find a way to know which object to deserialize into.

Is it possible to somehow get the method value when deserializing the data object or is there some other better way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar problem: as pointed out by Tomek you'll need a custom deserializer, along with a particular JSON field which you'll use at runtime to decide which subclass to instance.

Consider the following class as the base class:

```
// Base class for a server sent event
public class ServerEvent 
{
    public static final String TYPEFIELDNAME = "eventType";

    // Event type is used during deserialization to choose the right subclass
    private final String eventType;

    public ServerEvent(String eventType) 
    {
        this.eventType = eventType;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "eventType: " + eventType;
    }
}
```

ServerEvent has two subclasses, each one with different properties:

```
public class EventA extends ServerEvent 
{   
    private static final String EVENTTYPE = "eventa";
    private int data;

    public EventA() 
    {
        super(EVENTTYPE);
    }

    // Helper function to register this class with ServerEventDeserializer
    public static void register(ServerEventDeserializer deserializer) 
    {
        deserializer.registerEvent(EVENTTYPE, EventA.class);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString() + ", data = " + data;
    }
}

public class EventB extends ServerEvent 
{   
    private static final String EVENTTYPE = "eventb";
    private String name;

    public EventB() 
    {
        super(EVENTTYPE);
    }

    // Helper function to register this class with ServerEventDeserializer
    public static void register(ServerEventDeserializer deserializer) 
    {
        deserializer.registerEvent(EVENTTYPE, EventB.class);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString() + ", name = " + name;
    }
}
```

Two possible inputs could be the following:

```
{ "eventType" : "eventa", "data" : 15 }
{ "eventType" : "eventb", "name" : "test" }
```

This is the polymorphic deserializer:

```
// This class handles the polymorphic deserialization of ServerEvent class
public class ServerEventDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ServerEvent>
{
    // Gson engine
    private Gson gson;

    // Map of subclasses
    private Map<String, Class<? extends ServerEvent>> eventRegistry;

    public ServerEventDeserializer()
    {
        gson = new Gson();
        eventRegistry = new HashMap<String, Class<? extends ServerEvent>>();
    }

    // Registers a ServerEvent subclass
    public void registerEvent(String event, Class<? extends ServerEvent> eventInstanceClass)
    {
        eventRegistry.put(event, eventInstanceClass);
    }

    @Override
    public ServerEvent deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the JSON object
            JsonObject commandObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

            // Read the field named "ServerEvent.TYPEFIELDNAME"
            JsonElement commandTypeElement = commandObject.get(ServerEvent.TYPEFIELDNAME);

            // Query the eventRegistry map to instance the right subclass
            Class<? extends ServerEvent> commandInstanceClass = eventRegistry.get(commandTypeElement.getAsString());
            ServerEvent command = gson.fromJson(json, commandInstanceClass);

            return command;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote a minimal working example that can be downloaded [here](https://hostr.co/X1qb7UiguFI9).

Answer (score 0):

When you are deserializing this example json string custom deserializer will have method header like that:

```
public YOUR_CLASS deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
```

(add this deserializer by registerTypeAdapter() method in GsonBuilder object)

You can convert JsonElement to string, extract your methodParameters and based on something typical for each RequestData subclass you can instantiate specific class.
Lets say for instance that we have MyRequestData, this class has 10 parameters. I'm checking my json string, and if it has so many parameters return this specific instance. Of course you can firstly deserialize methodParameters (in deserializer class) to Map class for example and then analyze it to choose right class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can't look at the number of parameters as two methods can have the same amount of parameters. They should even be able to have exactly the same parameters. Can you elaborate the deserialization of the methodparams?

Comment: Ok later I will. But I have a question, what is the difference between these classes? Only implementation of certain methods? In such case it's impossible to recognize them. Then you can simply add additional parameter, for example "name" and in constructor set name of your specific class. That will be the simplest solution. Deserialization will be easy then.